# Muliptle Entries in single box on CMS?

Tags: custom-fields

I'm trying to create a directory of pet stores in UK&Ireland and I would like to know how I can input the brands each store carries into the CMS.It is just me doing the data entry so I wanted to be able to copt / paste from each store website and past their a-z of brand into one box but I've been told by my website designer that it isn't possible to do this as the results get mixed up ? Is this the case and how can I avoid months of manual entry and possible human error ?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at creating a channel to store the brands in and a channel to store the stores in. This way you can use the relationship fieldtype to link the pair together.

Dave.

Comment: I used to use this approach, but it isn't a good idea by performance issues. If you can use categories instead of relationships, you should.

Comment: Setting this up using categories doesn't feel right. A brand is a singular where as a category would suggest multiples. It well be less of a performance hit though.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. Polly did you finally resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just paste all data into one single form field, is going to be really hard to:

- to filter entries by this data;
- to format the presentation of the this data;
- to edit part of this data;

Imagine that one brand closes or change its name. How will you edit all stores at once? How will you list all stores by brand?

And copy/paste process isn't a good way to avoid possible human error.

I believe the best way is to use categories as brands and hire an backend developer, **not a designer**, to code a program that grab the data and turns into categories.